# Difference between the open/close curly brace instead of open/close double quote to interpret a string in PHP

Tags: php, curly-braces

I read the PHP manual and its wasn't really clear on any differences. I am confused as to what would the point of using this:

```
echo "Print this {$test} here.";
```

compared to this be:

```
echo "Print this $test here.";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, there is no difference. However, it is helpful when the variable expression is more complex, like an array with a string index. For example:

```
$arr['string'] = 'thing';

echo "Print a {$arr['string']}";
// result: "Print a thing";

echo "Print a $arr['string']";
// result: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE
```

Answer (score 4):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.

Example:

```
<?php
// Show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$great = 'fantastic';

// Won't work, outputs: This is { fantastic}
echo "This is { $great}";

// Works, outputs: This is fantastic
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";

// Works
echo "This square is {$square->width}00 centimeters broad."; 


// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";


// Works
echo "This works: {$arr[4][3]}";

// This is wrong for the same reason as $foo[bar] is wrong  outside a string.
// In other words, it will still work, but only because PHP first looks for a
// constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be
// thrown.
echo "This is wrong: {$arr[foo][3]}"; 

// Works. When using multi-dimensional arrays, always use braces around arrays
// when inside of strings
echo "This works: {$arr['foo'][3]}";

// Works.
echo "This works: " . $arr['foo'][3];

echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]->name}";

echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of \$object->getName(): {${$object->getName()}}";

// Won't work, outputs: This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}
echo "This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}";
?>
```

See that page for more examples.